# ATL ActiveX Font Property

Tags: fonts, activex, atl, toolbox

I am beginning to develop a series of custom ATL ActiveX controls for a new project and am using the ATL Project Wizard. Looking ahead I want to ensure that the controls can be used in both C# and VC++.

I have run into an issue where I can create a C# project, drop my control on a form and change the font property. The rendered text is immediately redrawn in the newly selected font.

However, when I create a MFC-based project in VC++, drop my control on a dialog and change the font property. The rendered text is NOT redrawn in the newly selected font. If I move my control on the dialog, the the test does get redrawn correctly

What gives? Both application frameworks are hosted within the same MSVS 2010 environment and used the same toolbox but behave differently. I have searched for an answer for hours but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could just be that the MFC dialog designer is a bit ancient compared to the WinForms designer, and so has a few bugs in it. It might be better to test that at *run-time*, changing the Font property updates immediately in both situations. The MFC dialog designer might simply not be firing off the right message at the right time - or might not be repainting at appropriate moments.

Comment: No issues at run-time. Thanks